# int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'tuple'

Tags: python, sql, string, tkinter

so baiscally my code in this section is supposed to get a value from a sql database and add the tkinter value onto it then put the value back into the sql database

```
    with sqlite3.connect('aircraft.db') as db:
        c = db.cursor()
        self.flightcount4 = self.flightcount5.get()
        self.flightcount3 = int(self.flightcount4)

        c.execute("SELECT flightcount FROM aircraft WHERE Arrive = ?",(self.travelselect.get(),))
        self.total3 = c.fetchone()
        total2 = int(self.total3)
        self.total = total2 + self.flightcount3
        c.execute('UPDATE aircraft SET flightcount = :flightcount WHERE Arrive = :Arrive',{'flightcount':self.flightcount3, 'aircraftpilot':self.pilotname5 })
        db.commit()
        ms.showinfo('Success!', 'its saved!')
```

this is my code.

```
 Exception in Tkinter callback
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\Users\adam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36- 
 32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1702, in __call__
 return self.func(*args)
 File "C:\A LEVELS\Computing\atom\actual results\working\Customer.py", 
 line 40, in addtocount
 total2 = int(self.total3)
 TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a 
 number, not 'tuple'
 [Finished in 30.761s]
```

this is the error.

since then i have came up with this with your help:

```
 def addtocount(self):

    with sqlite3.connect('aircraft.db') as db:
        c = db.cursor()
        self.flightcount4 = self.flightcount5.get()
        self.flightcount3 = int(self.flightcount4)

        c.execute("SELECT flightcount FROM aircraft WHERE Arrive = ?",(self.travelselect.get(),))
        self.total3 = c.fetchone()[0]
        print(self.total3)
        if self.total3 == "None":
            self.total2 == int("0")
            print(self.total2)
        else:
            self.total2 = self.total3
        self.total = self.total2 + self.flightcount3
        c.execute('UPDATE aircraft SET flightcount = :flightcount WHERE Arrive = :Arrive',{'flightcount':self.flightcount3, 'aircraftpilot':self.pilotname5 })
        db.commit()
        ms.showinfo('Success!', 'its saved!')
```

but now the error is:

```
  File "C:\A LEVELS\Computing\atom\actual results\working\Customer.py", line 46, in addtocount
self.total = self.total2 + self.flightcount3
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'int'
[Finished in 15.573s]
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know `c.fetchone()` fetches the whole row. Even if you only specify one value in the SQL-statement it will be wrapped in a tuple. Syntax wise it will look something like this if you tried to print it:

```
('flightcount value')
```

Pay notice those pesky parentheses around the value.

The reason you get the error is because `int(self.total3)` tries to parse the whole tuple (row) from `c.fetchone()`. Instead you need to select the specific column from the row, like this:

```
int(self.total3[0])
```

Comment: I tried doing this and it came out with the same error, i also tried a different approach because i have 9 columns in the sql database i tried [8] and [9] and both said out of index any  chance you know why? thank you

Comment: @AdamWilson Is it *exactly* the same error as before? Try to see what the actual value in `self.total3` is by adding a `print(self.total3)` right after `self.total3 = c.fetchone()`, as well as `print(self.total3[0])` just to make sure there's actually a value in there.

Comment: Also mind that you only need to care about the index of the column name that you specify in your `SELECT`-clause. If your select clause looks like `SELECT flightcount, Arrive FROM ...`, then `flightcount` is on index 0, and `Arrive` is on index 1 no matter how they're organised in the actual database.

Comment: the print of self.total3[0] is "none"

Comment: if you look at the code above i have added a bit on due to the fact i can not put the code onto this. this is the direction i believe i should be going but it is still not working @Johan

Comment: In that case i believe that `flightcount` doesn't contain a value for that `Arrive` filter. Have you made sure you've spelt all the columns correctly and that they map to the columns in the database? I believe they're case sensitive as well.

Comment: Really sorry for the time this has taken up its just i have been stuck on this for ages, would it be helpful for me to put the whole code onto the page for you to run and see?

Comment: Unfortunately not, it's impossible to debug since it's also depending on your data in the database. Since you previously said `self.total3[0]` is "none"  there's just no data being fetched from the database. If that's caused by faulty code, wrong select-statement or it just not being any data in your database is impossible to tell from the code, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

The error is exactly what Python tells you: `int()` can only accept strings, bytes (another kind of string), or numbers, and you are passing a tuple. This means that `self.total3` is some set of values wrapped like this: `(x,y,z)`.

Looking at sqlite's Python docs, it seems that it returns database rows as tuples, with each tuple slot representing a column of the database. You can unwrap the tuple with assignment or indexing:

```py
col1, col2, col3 = row  # where row is (col1, col2, col3)
col1 = row[0]  # indexed from 0
```

When you encounter an issue like this, my first step is to always find the offensive value in question (here the "int() argument" that the compiler points out to us, `self.total3`) and simply `print()` it in order to see what looks wrong.

You probably don't need to be introducing all of these class state variables (`self.xyz`) if you aren't using them outside of this context. It would be simpler to use local variables for anything that is only used in this context.

Comment: would i need to add the "col1, col2, col3 = row" to the code then because if not i tried this approach as i have 9 columns in the sql database and the flight count is the 9th

Comment: i would use the appropriate number of `col*` variables for whatever table i was using, this was just a example

Answer (score 1):

```
self.total3 = c.fetchone()
total2 = int(self.total3)
```

Here, `self.total3` is the whole row. Even if you selected a single value, the return value is wrapped in a tuple. You need to get your value from the tuple.

```
self.total3 = c.fetchone()[0]
total2 = int(self.total3)
```

Answer (score 1):

`fetchone()` returns a tuple, since it supports retrieving a row of multiple things. In your case you selected a single thing (`flightcount`), but you still have to treat the return value as a tuple. So it should be:

```
self.total3 = c.fetchone()[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try accessing the first element:

int(self.total3[0])

or

self.total3 = cursor.fetchone()[0]

Answer (score 0):

int() can only parse one value, not a tuple. What you can do is:

```
total2 = [int(value) for value in self.total3]
```

then, you have the tuple values in a list of integers.

Comment: I think the answer of Johan rather states what you wanted.